# Pdf Highlight store and access

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, highlight, syncfusion

I am trying to highlight the content of pdf and save and store it so that next time when user open that pdf he/she will can access the highlighted items. I am using syncfusion_flutter_pdf package for this. Till now I am able to highlight contents but I am not able to store and access highlighted contents.
My code is:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();
  PdfViewerController controller = PdfViewerController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.bookmark,
              color: Colors.white,
              semanticLabel: 'Bookmark',
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _pdfViewerKey.currentState?.openBookmarkView();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SfPdfViewer.asset(
        'assets/name.pdf',
        controller: controller,
        onAnnotationSelected: (Annotation annotation) {
          annotation.addListener(() {});
          
        },
        onAnnotationAdded: (Annotation annotation) {
          annotation.color = Colors.yellow;
          log('selected lines ${controller.getAnnotations()}');
        },
        onAnnotationDeselected: (Annotation annotation) {
          annotation.color = Colors.white;
        },
        onAnnotationEdited: (Annotation annotation) {
          annotation.color = Colors.blue;
        },
        onAnnotationRemoved: (Annotation annotation) {},
        key: _pdfViewerKey,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to get the solution for storing and accessing highlighted pdf contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [saveDocument](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/latest/pdfviewer/PdfViewerController/saveDocument.html) method to save the annotations to the document. On reopening the same document, the highlighted contents will be preserved.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();
  PdfViewerController controller = PdfViewerController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.save,
            ),
            onPressed: _save,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<File>(
          future: _getPdf(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              return SfPdfViewer.file(
                snapshot.data!,
                controller: controller,
                key: _pdfViewerKey,
                onAnnotationAdded: (annotation) {
                  annotation.author = 'Guest';
                  annotation.subject = 'Text Markup';
                },
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          }),
    );
  }

  Future<File> _getPdf() async {
    final Directory dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final File file = File('${dir.path}/temp.pdf');

    // Check if the file exists
    if (file.existsSync()) {
      // If file exists, return the file
      return file;
    } else {
      // If file don't exists, create the file from asset and return it
      final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/name.pdf');
      final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();      
      await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
      return file;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _save() async {
    final Directory dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    // Saving the file to a temporary location
    final File file = File('${dir.path}/temp.pdf');

    // Save annotations to the PDF document
    final List<int> bytes = await controller.saveDocument();
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understood and implemented what you have given in the code. But my next problem is that I want to save highlighted content immediately after highlighting not by any save button. I tried calling _save() method in 'onAnnotationAdded', but pdf will reload and jump to page number 1 everytime.Here is my latest code: –  [   https://github.com/shankarbhattarai123/pdf_test   ]

Comment: Can you check whether the reloading issue is resolved with the changes in https://github.com/shankarbhattarai123/pdf_test/pull/2/files?